# SQL insert and id with auto_increment

Tags: sql, insert, auto-increment

Hey ya'll I have this insert statement here

```
INSERT INTO persons VALUES (16,'First Name',NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,now(),NULL,NULL);
```

it says that the number of columns do not match because the last column is for the id which is auto incremented.  do I have to put in an id value?

Thanks,
J

Comment: What version of sql is this? MySql, SQL Server, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not include an Auto-increment column in your insert.

It is also best practice to put the column names after the table name.  This helps to make the query cleaner and easier to read & maintain.

```
INSERT INTO persons(Column1, col2, ...)
VALUES (16, 'First Name', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't include that field 
INSERT INTO persons VALUES (16,'First Name',NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,now(),NULL);